# Programming Languages - Game Development

Tags: game-engine

I was wondering how I would go about creating a game. I do not care if it is only available on windows or it is cross-platform. Which languages would I use to create a game?

Answer (score 1):

**Q: Which languages would I use to create a game?**

**A:** One could program a game in almost any known programming language. Different languages work better or worse for different types of games, so it really depends.

**Remark:** Without extensive knowledge of how even simple games like PacMan are coded, you will run into many issues when trying to code a more complex game. I highly recommend you try to write a simple PacMan or Tetris game using only `Java`, just to get a hang of things and then from there move on to more and more complex games and only then start to being with more complex game languages.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 While I do agree with you, I'd like to point out the Java is one of the most mainstream languages and if one can master Java then mastering other languages will be a piece of cake.

Comment: @Tdorno - You may want to follow some of those links. ;)

Comment: Processing is a powerful Java dialect for visual designers; it's syntax was inspired by Design by Numbers and PostScript. It hides the most frustrating things about Java programming and it's very easy to start. You could give it a try: http://www.processing.org/